# How can i make the text in the label move like in (marquee) if the label width not fit the text width in C# windows form application?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to make the label text move as in marquee but in windows form application , thanks.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want the text to resize?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to scroll text that is too large to fit in its label (something like what a media player does when listing a song title and artist?

Comment: If you do choose to implement a scrolling text (marquee) approach, you may need to detect those situations where the text is too large for the area allocated for the label control. I haven't tried this myself, but there is a MeasureString method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0ae0hxt.aspx) on the System.Drawing.Graphics class that looks like it can tell you how much area a string requires if drawn with the given font: http://www.dev102.com/2008/10/09/measure-string-size-in-pixels-c/ Of course, if you choose to scroll the text every time, then there's no need to check the size.

Comment: very sorry for the bad explanation of the question but if there is a way to make the label text move as in marquee but in windows form application it would help too much , thanks.

Comment: The other answer to this question had a link to a page that gave an example of how to scroll text, but the person who posted that answer deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't exactly clear where you might want to move the text to, if it doesn't fit the layout then there are no real options.  In general, window layouts are contrained width-wise but have some room for growth vertically.  Enforce this by setting the Label's MaximumSize property to, say, (100,0) so it cannot grow in the width and overlap some other control.  That will make it start wrapping text and use more vertical space.

If that's a problem as well then set AutoSize = False and AutoEllipsis = True.  The user can now tell that the text got truncated.  And automatically gets a tooltip when she hovers the label.

Comment: very sorry for the bad explanation of the question but if there is a way to make the label text move as in marquee but in windows form application it would help too much , thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry too.  I recommend you use my advice, users absolutely despise stuff that moves for no good reason.